# Prevent replacing of .net 4 dlls when installing .net 4.5

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I have a solution that contains dlls from janus that ate compatible with .net 4.

After I installed visual studio 2012 - the application throws an exception : "the member is not supported in a dynamic assembly" although I open it with visual studio 2010.

I could uninstall .net 4.5 and then reinstalling .net 4 but then visual studio 2012 wont work.

Anyone knows a way I can keep vs2012 and .net 4's dlls?

Comment: Did you upgrade your project to 2012? Also, what libraries specifically are giving you errors>

Comment: No, I opened an 2010 solution in vs 2010. And every janus dll is giving me the error (timeline, gridex, etc...)

Comment: I'd say it's the Janus controls that are the problem. You may need a newer version.  Reference: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q435047, related: http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/vagif/archive/2010/07/02/net-4-0-and-notsupportedexception-complaining-about-dynamic-assemblies.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can't have them both, .Net 4.5 is an in-place upgrade to 4.0.

References:

- [Compatibility of .NET Framework 4.5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/compatibility-of-net-framework-4-5/)
- [Does .net 4.5 work side by side with .net 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745600/does-net-4-5-work-side-by-side-with-net-4-0)
- [Does installing .NET 4.5 REALLY replace .NET 4.0 assemblies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011883/does-installing-net-4-5-really-replace-net-4-0-assemblies?rq=1)
- [.NET 4.5 and .NET 4 Won't Coexist](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Home.aspx)

Comment: Although, this breaking VS 2010 is hit or miss. I have had no problems with VS 2010 since installing 4.5 and VS 2012.